# Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. Help PLS

Tags: mysql

So curently I am confrunting with this problem... I tried a lot of things to fix this but none worked. I typed `systemctl status mysqld` the output is:

```
mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-02-02 04:31:29 EST; 12min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 12230 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 12207 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 12230 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Data Dictionary upgrade from MySQL 5.7 in progress"

Feb 02 04:31:28 vladismv.perrico.uk systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Feb 02 04:31:29 vladismv.perrico.uk systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 02 04:31:29 vladismv.perrico.uk systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Feb 02 04:31:29 vladismv.perrico.uk systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Feb 02 04:31:29 vladismv.perrico.uk systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

I tried to do

```
ls -la /var/lib |grep mysql
```

and output is

```
drwxr-x--x   5 mysql   mysql   4096 Feb  2 04:31 mysql
drwxr-x---   2 mysql   mysql   4096 Dec 11 03:49 mysql-files
drwxr-x---   2 mysql   mysql   4096 Dec 11 03:49 mysql-keyring
drwxr-x--x   8 mysql   mysql   4096 Feb  1 07:18 mysql_old_backup
```

if you know what to do don't hezitate to write me

Answer (score 0):

Did you have anything important in your database, that wasn't backed up?
If not just delete the content of data directory, should be `/var/lib/mysql`